# How to get 2 unrelated Swift objects to know how to do the same sets of function

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Before anyone says inheritance.. hear me out first.

I have 2 totally unrelated view controllers. They each have an `MKMapView`. I would like both of them to conform to and implement the same delegate methods.

For example, I want both to implement:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polyline = overlay as! MKPolyline
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        renderer.lineWidth = 4
        return renderer
    }
```

Again, these 2 view controllers aren't related at all, so I don't want to make a base class. As a matter of fact, these 2 view controllers are already inheriting from their respective inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018677/what-is-where-self-in-protocol-extension ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a protocol and a default implementation.

```
protocol SomeMapFunctions {
    var mapView : MKMapView? { get }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
}

extension SomeMapFunctions {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polyline = overlay as! MKPolyline
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        renderer.lineWidth = 4
        return renderer
    }
}

class VC1 : UIViewController, SomeMapFunctions {
    var mapView : MKMapView?
}

class VC2 : UIViewController, SomeMapFunctions {
    var mapView : MKMapView?
}
```

As shown, any common properties that are necessary for the default implementations can be put into the protocol as well.

Comment: Ahh... the good old `extension` for default implementation trick.. I forgot about this!! Thanks.. it was so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
protocol CommonStuff {
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer 
}

extension CommonStuff where Self: UIViewController {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polyline = overlay as! MKPolyline
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        renderer.lineWidth = 4
        return renderer
    }
}
```

Then, adopting the protocol by both view controllers would provide them the same behaviour.