# Objective C syntax corresponding to Swift "extension where self: <some protocol>"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there any way to extend a class in Objective C only for those subclasses that conform to a protocol, like that in Swift:

```
extension SomeClass where self: SomeProtocol {
// some code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Could you provide this as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Objective-C syntax for that. (Not sure if there’s even a Swift syntax like this; we have a [generic where clause](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID553), but not on `self`. And Objective-C doesn’t offer full generic implementation, only offering lightweight implementation.)

Comment: There is a `where self` (well, tather `where Self:`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018677/what-is-where-self-in-protocol-extension

Comment: Yep, for Swift protocols, but not classes. And not in ObjC.